# Simple example to upload photos into google picasa

Tags: picasa

I would like to move a large number of pictures into picassa. I'm having no trouble uploading using InsertPhotoSimple, but I want to upload metadata too and am having trouble with InsertPhoto. Can anyone point me to a simple example or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/python

import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
gd_client.email = 'my_google_email'
gd_client.password = 'my_pass'
gd_client.source = 'my_source'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

album_url = '/data/feed/api/user/%s/albumid/%s' % ('default', 'default')
filename = 'myfile.jpg'
metadata = gdata.photos.PhotoEntry()
metadata.title = 'My Photo Title'
metadata.media.keywords = 'keyword1, keyword2, keyword3'

upload_photo = gd_client.InsertPhoto(album_url, metadata, filename, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

But when I run this, it chokes every time with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./picassa.py", line 36, in ?
    upload_photo = gd_client.InsertPhoto(album_url, metadata, filename, content_type='image/jpeg')
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/gdata/photos/service.py", line 425, in InsertPhoto
    converter=gdata.photos.PhotoEntryFromString)
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/gdata/service.py", line 1236, in Post
    media_source=media_source, converter=converter)
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/gdata/service.py", line 1286, in PostOrPut
    data_str = str(data)
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/atom/**init**.py", line 377, in **str**
    return self.ToString()
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/atom/**init**.py", line 374, in ToString
    return ElementTree.tostring(self._ToElementTree(), encoding=string_encoding)
  File "/home1/alptownc/public_html/photos/gdata-2.0.13/atom/**init**.py", line 369, in _ToElementTree
    self._AddMembersToElementTree(new_tree)

I know I'm missing something stupid and simple, but I can't see what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `insertPhotoEntry` instead of just `insertPhoto` ?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your code, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it. I found this link to Google Developers which may help.

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php#PostPhotos